# How to create a file within a shell script having different owner group permission?

Tags: shell, unix, owner

I have a shell script with owner permission as `owner1`. In that shell script I am creating a file.

Now the problem is I am executing the file with `owner2` group. So the error is throwing at the file creation line as

`Permission denied`

How to execute the shell script with different owner group?

Comment: Use `su` or `sudo` as appropriate to your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `chown` or `chgrp` in your script to assign the file to `owner2` ?

an other option I see is to `sudo` (su) when creating the file so it is created under `owner2` while the script is executed as `owner1`.